# What is the fastest way to copy the first 100k folders from one directory to another in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have a directory with around 500K folders and I want to copy 100K folders within this directory to another directory.

Currently, I have taken the paths to the 100K folders and then copying them to another directory using:

```
while read line; do cp -R $line <dest_folder>; done < file_with_paths.txt
```

The above approach takes a lot of time copying one folder (each folder basically has 2 files), every 2 seconds.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: fastest will be using: rsync (from my experience and tests years ago; also check for options to use in your case

Comment: Probably not much quicker. I/O will be the bottle neck here. If you want smarter, you will have to define what that means.

Comment: @Drako. How much quicker though? Certainly a better idea because for that quantity error recovery may be a consideration and rsync is much better than basic cp at that.

Comment: I did tests like ~ 5 years ago - don't have tests - but you can redo - but was better for huge amounts for me then :)

Comment: Running `cp` 100K times introduces its own overhead beyond whatever I/O is needed. Using `rsync` addresses that, at least.

Answer (score 1):

I would use xargs from GNU finutils package :

```
xargs -P 1 cp -r -t dest_folder < file_with_paths.txt
```

- `-P 1` tells `xargs` to run only on subprocess at a time as cp does not parallel very well
- `cp` is used with `-t` as `xargs` put argument at the end of the command

This command will run few cp, each with the maximum possible folders as argument. If you want to control how many folders are copied by each cp, use `-L` option, like `-L 999`.

Note that is can be combined with a `ls -1 | head -n 100000` if "file_with_paths.txt" is not build beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I often use `tar` to copy hierarchies

untested

```
cd /path/to/source/directory
<file_with_paths.txt xargs sh -c '
    tar cf - "$@" | (cd /path/to/destination/directory && tar xf -)
' sh
```

I can imagine this will be slower than rsync